# Pandas DataFrame - Rolling column value_counts() for string/Boolean occurrence count

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a rolling DataFrame window over 3, 5 or 7 days/rows which counts the occurrences of ‘UP’ and ’DOWN’ in the theDF[‘Growth’] column and shows the highest occurrence value in the column theDF[‘Trend’], i.e...

DataFrame output Window:

[image: Screenshot DataFrame output Window]

I have been able to use the theDF[‘growth’].value_counts() to get the occurrences for the complete DataFrame, but I haven’t been able to yet do this over a rolling window of 3, 5 or 7 days/rows.

Here is my current code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)


inFilename = 'ETC-EUR Complete Dataset.csv'
theDF = pd.read_csv(inFilename)

theDF['Growth'] = np.where(theDF.Open > theDF.Close, 'DOWN', 'UP')

print(theDF['Growth'].value_counts())


print(theDF.head(9))
```

Here is my console output:

[image: Screenshot console output]

Comment: Do you want to get the value_counts for index at 3,5 and 7?

Comment: I want the rolling window to be of size 3, 5, 7 days/row etc... and to display the output in another data frame column. I want this to keep rolling through the data frame.

Comment: What's the rolling window? There's no column named rolling window in your df shown.

Comment: That is the DataFrame.rolling(window=3 or 5 or any arbitrary number) command that I am trying to implement on the theDF['Growth'] column. Look at the output window picture Joe, this will show you what I am trying to get to.  I'm not sure, but I was reading an article detailing how this is a limitation of the Python DataFrame library. And it not being able to count string values when using the rolling() method.

Comment: @Joe
I have been able to perform this task by using 0 to represent DOWN and 1 to represent UP.
'import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

inFilename = 'ETC-EUR Complete Dataset.csv'
theDF = pd.read_csv(inFilename)

theDF['Growth'] = np.where(theDF.Open > theDF.Close, '0', '1')
theDF['Inter'] = theDF['Growth'].rolling(window=5).median()
theDF['Trend'] = np.where(theDF.Growth == '0', 'DOWN', 'UP')

print(theDF['Growth'].value_counts())

print(theDF)'